# BigQuery Web Editor star expansion columns in SELECT

Tags: google-bigquery

Given the below code, I'd like to expand the `*` to the list of columns in the `FROM` clause. Some places refer to this as "star expansion". SQL Server/Dbeaver are able to do this by pressing `CTRL+Space` or other shortcuts. Is there a way to do this in the BigQuery Web UI Editor?

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
  `analytics-dev.my_dataset.my_table`
```

If `my_table` has 4 columns, pressing the shortcut keyword would expand to:

```
SELECT
    col1, col2, col3, col4
FROM
  `analytics-dev.my_dataset.my_table`
```

Comment: Don't think so, but it does have a nifty except() clause so if you're doing that to modify one column, you can do select * except(col4), col4+1 as col4 from my_table

Comment: I did not see any recorded documentation of this function. I would suggest filing an issue request for this matter please see the steps by visiting this site: https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests. Please be guided that Feature Request does not have ETA but instead you can star an request to gain traction.

Comment: @NestorCenizaJr Added here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/242148085

Comment: I also changed it from "bug" to "Feature Request."

Answer (score 0):

You can use 3rd party IDE for BigQuery supporting this and many more perks
This is Goliath - part of [Potens.io](https://potensio.zendesk.com/) Suite available at [Marketplace](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/potens-io/potensio).

[image]

when user pick [highlighted] option - the query editor is populated as in below screenshot (not exactly expansion as it is asked in your question)

[image]

Yet expansion is also supported but with few more steps

- navigate to table by CTRL + Click on table reference + SPACE
- then choosing "Insert all fields" - obviously making sure cursor is in proper place in Editor ...

***Note**: Another tool in this suite is Magnus - Workflow Automator. Supports all BigQuery, Cloud Storage and most of Google APIs as well as multiple simple utility type Tasks like BigQuery Task, Export to Storage Task, Loop Task and many many more along with advanced scheduling, triggering, etc. Supports GitHub as a source control as well*

***Disclosure**: I am GDE for Google Cloud and creator of those tools and leader on Potens team*